# Зафиксировать заголовки в верху таблицы при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица заголовки типа как на рисунке, не могу зафиксировать если там есть объеденные ячейки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример того что я хочу увидеть - [ссылка | jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flytrap/g2cxd0jj)

Пробовал фиксировать вот так

```css
.scrolGridTerminal {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
}

.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(3) {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolGridTerminal">
  <table class="table-scrolGridTerminal" cellspacing="0" rules="all" name="GridView3" border="1" id="MainContent_GridView3" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="9">header</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="centre_align" rowspan="2">№ ktk</th>
        <th class="centre_align" colspan="2">arrival</th>
        <th class="centre_align" rowspan="2">№ auto</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">date</th>
        <th scope="col">time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>5122073</td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          12548
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.scrolGridTerminal {
    overflow: scroll;
height: 150px;  
}

tr th:nth-child(1) {
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 1px;
  background: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px
}

tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2), tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(3){
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  background: black;
    color: white
}

tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(2){
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 46px;
  background: red;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolGridTerminal">
<table class="table-scrolGridTerminal" cellspacing="0" rules="all" name="GridView3" border="1" id="MainContent_GridView3" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="in-tr">
        <th colspan="9">
        header
        </th>
      </tr>
    <tr class="in-tr">
      <th class="centre_align" rowspan="2">№ ktk</th>
      <th class="centre_align" colspan="2">arrival</th>
      <th class="centre_align" rowspan="2">№ auto</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="in-tr">
      <th scope="col">date</th>
      <th scope="col">time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
      <td>5122073</td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label2_0">15.10.2019</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView3_Label3_0">08:27:06  </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        12548
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: фиксация заголовков не работает

Comment: @Konst - благодарю - в хроме не работало, переделал

Comment: Спасибо наконецто то что надо

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!

Comment: А можно как то сделать границу ячеек, вот например между 2 и 3 строчкой видно как листается таблица. Но при этом чтобы быд border

Comment: Конечно можно - но придется повозиться - попробуйте, задавать лучше через маскирующий div в th